# Action Not Found For request 'GET /authenticate/github? in securesocial for playframwork 2.6

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.6, securesocial

I have been trying to use securesocial in play 2.6. I am using master snapshot. When I click on GitHub icon, it navigates me to github.com and when I enter my username and password, I get action not found error http://localhost:9000/authenticate/github?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=9eb23bec-37b6-4930-9b76-899ff8e1fbe1.

Below is my route file

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /home                       @controllers.Application.goHome

GET     /userAware                  @controllers.Application.userAware
GET     /link-result                @controllers.Application.linkResult
GET     /current-user               @controllers.Application.currentUser

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

->      /auth                       securesocial.Routes
```

**Application.java**

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.Logger;
import play.libs.F;
import  services.MyUserService;
import securesocial.core.BasicProfile;
import securesocial.core.RuntimeEnvironment;
import securesocial.core.java.SecureSocial;
import securesocial.core.java.SecuredAction;
import securesocial.core.java.UserAwareAction;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.function.Function;

import views.html.*;

/**
 * This controller contains an action to handle HTTP requests
 * to the application's home page.
 */
public class Application extends Controller {

    /**
     * An action that renders an HTML page with a welcome message.
     * The configuration in the <code>routes</code> file means that
     * this method will be called when the application receives a
     * <code>GET</code> request with a path of <code>/</code>.
     */

   public static Logger.ALogger logger = Logger.of("application.controllers.Application");
    private RuntimeEnvironment env;

    /**
     * A constructor needed to get a hold of the environment instance.
     * This could be injected using a DI framework instead too.
     *
     * @param env
     */
    @Inject()
    public Application (RuntimeEnvironment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }
    /**
     * This action only gets called if the user is logged in.
     *
     * @return
     */

    @SecuredAction
    public Result index() {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("access granted to index");
        }
        MyUserService user = (MyUserService) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
        return ok(index.render(user, SecureSocial.env()));
    }

    @UserAwareAction
    public Result userAware() {
        MyUserService myUser = (MyUserService) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
        String userName ;
        if ( myUser != null ) {
            BasicProfile user = myUser.main;
            if ( user.firstName().isDefined() ) {
                userName = user.firstName().get();
            } else if ( user.fullName().isDefined()) {
                userName = user.fullName().get();
            } else {
                userName = "authenticated user";
            }
        } else {
            userName = "guest";
        }
        return ok("Hello " + userName + ", you are seeing a public page");
    }

    @SecuredAction
    public Result goHome() {
         if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("access granted to Home");
    }
    MyUserService user = (MyUserService) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
        return ok(home.render());
    }

    @SecuredAction
    public Result linkResult() {
        MyUserService current = (MyUserService) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
        return ok(linkResult.render(current, current.identities));
    }

    /**
     * Sample use of SecureSocial.currentUser. Access the /current-user to test it
     */
    public CompletionStage<Result> currentUser() {
        return SecureSocial.currentUser(env).thenApply( new Function<Object, Result>() {
            public Result apply(Object maybeUser) {
                String id;

                if ( maybeUser != null ) {
                    MyUserService user = (MyUserService) maybeUser;
                    id = user.main.userId();
                } else {
                    id = "not available. Please log in.";
                }
                return ok("your id is " + id);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in securesocial.conf I have added `onLoginGoTo = /home`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use `/authenticate` rather than `/auth`:

```
->      /authenticate                       securesocial.Routes
```

Or if you want to use the url use it with `auth` and not `authenticate`:

```
http://localhost:9000/auth/github?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=9eb23bec-37b6-4930-9b76-899ff8e1fbe1
```

Comment: I am using the sample application on [link](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/java/demo), . the example has `/auth` in securesecure.conf file.

Comment: even after changing `/auth` to `/authenticate` I get the same error. Please look the screenshot i have attached to the initial post

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I did not add route to redirect URL in my route file.
After adding `->    /authenticate/github  securesocial.Routes` solved my problem. `/authenticate/github` was the URL I registered while creating client token on github